# Inequality $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} \geq a + b+ c$ when $abc = 1$

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c > 0$ are such that $abc=1$, then
>   $$ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} \geq a + b+ c. $$

I would be pleased if you give me a hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}  = \frac{a^2c+b^2a+bc^2}{abc} = a^2c+b^2a+bc^2$...can you take it from here?

Answer (score 8):

$$a+b+c =$$

$$\{ \mbox{multiply by 1: maybe } abc\mbox{, maybe }\sqrt{abc}, ... \}$$

> $$= \frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}=$$

$$ 
=\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{b}{c}}
+\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{c} \cdot \frac{b}{c} \cdot \frac{c}{a}}
+\sqrt[3]{\frac{c}{a} \cdot \frac{c}{a} \cdot \frac{a}{b}}
\le
$$
$$
\{\mbox{ GM}\le\mbox{AM }\} 
$$
$$
\le \frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}}{3} 
+ \frac{\frac{b}{c}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}}{3}
+ \frac{\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{b}}{3} = 
$$
$$
=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}.
$$

Comment: Hi! I have always been fascinated by these seemingly contrived algebraic manipulations. Can I ask how you do them? Do you just try random manipulations until you recognize something? Or start with a goal of which inequality to use?

Comment: Hi @Ovi!
**First step** was to kill dimensions.
Imagine that $a,b,c$ are measured in 'meters'.
So, LHS is dimension-free, and RHS is $a+b+c\; (m)$; and we can imagine that $abc=1(m^3)$.
Therefore we divide RHS by $\sqrt[3]{abc} (meters)$ to "equalize" dimensions.

Then when you'll see $\sqrt[3]{\ldots}$, the most intuitive **second step** is to apply AM-GM. ...

Comment: ... Few links which are my lovely ones of this sort:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality;

here are few examples which can develop intuition in this branch:

https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Algebra/CyclicInequality1.shtml .